# How to store trait implementations together when the trait has associated types

Tags: generics, types, rust, traits, associated-types

Trait objects can be used when we want to store multiple types together in a collection.

But I don't know how to do this when the trait has associated types.

```rust
trait Error {}

trait Trait {
    type Error: Error;
    fn set(&mut self, key: String, value: String) -> Result<(), Self::Error>;
}

struct StructA;
impl Trait for StructA {
    type Error = ErrorA;
}

enum ErrorA {}
impl Error for ErrorA {}

struct StructB;
impl Trait for StructB {
    type Error = ErrorB;
}

enum ErrorB {}
impl Error for ErrorB {}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let value: Box<dyn Trait<Error = dyn Error>> = match 0 {
        0 => Box::new(StructA),
        _ => Box::new(StructB),
    };

    value.set(String::from("key"), String::from("value"))?;

    Ok(())
}
```

I have to specify the associated type `Box<dyn Trait<Error = _>>` here, but I don't know which type would fit. I tried `dyn Error` but it will not work.

Comment: @user4815162342 I just added a method for Trait

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can change `Trait`, you can make it object-safe for all error types by returning a dynamic error type to begin with, e.g. change the signature of `set()` to something like:

```
fn set(&mut self, key: String, value: String) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error + '_>>;
```

However, if you *can't* change `Trait` to make it object-safe, you can still create your own object-safe trait, and provide a blanket implementation for every type that implements `Trait`. For example:

```
trait DynamicTrait {
    fn set(&mut self, key: String, value: String) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error + '_>>;
}

impl<T: Trait> DynamicTrait for T {
    fn set(&mut self, key: String, value: String) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error + '_>> {
        Trait::set(self, key, value).map_err(|e| Box::new(e) as _)
    }
}
```

`DynamicTrait` works exactly like `Trait`, but returns `Box<dyn Error>` in case of error, so it's object-safe. For example, this just works without modifying the implementation of either `Trait` or its implementations `StructA` and `StructB`:

```
fn main() {
    let value: Box<dyn DynamicTrait> = match 0 {
        0 => Box::new(StructA),
        _ => Box::new(StructB),
    };
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3766b3daeacbe6bac4be6464b7c1d76f)

Comment: The second solution seems good to me. But in this way how can I return the error to `main` https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c3cb491247e76d20a87d7c0569996e6f

Comment: You just need to add `+ 'static` to the definition of `trait Error` to get that to compile. Then you can also get rid of the weird `+ '_` lifetime in the boxes. Adding `'static` just requires the error to only contain owned data, which is almost universally required of Rust errors anyway - I just assumed you couldn't modify the implementation of the error trait, so I didn't want to add the bound to my example.